# Organisations that inlcude "Industries" in their name

Tags: internal-consistency, organizations

I have noticed recently that in the Sci-Fi and Fantasy worlds a lot of organisations include “Industries” in their name e.g. Wayne Industries, Stark Industries, Lunar Industries, Trask Industries, Queen Industries and Weyland Industries to name a few. The assumption being that these organisations are big and diverse enough to compete in markets within two or more industries listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Classification_Benchmark

These organisations are often seen as powerful conglomerates with many revenue streams and high investment into research and development which is followed through into their own in-house manufacturing.  Before I create my own world in which such an organisation exists I wanted to study real world examples of companies that had “Industries” in their name but none came to mind. The hope being that I can take a real world example of similar organisation that competes in different industries and build it up.

Given the fact that in different interpretations and timelines of the worlds in which these organisations exists the word “Industries” is changed e.g. Queen Consolidated (Arrow) and Weyland-Yutani Corporation (AVP). This makes me think the word is purely used to infer a sense of grandeur and has no descriptive value.  In which case similar organisations might already exist but simply don’t contain “Industries” in their name.

The aim of this exercise is to help separate fantasy from reality in how big an organisation can realistically grow in power and diversity. There may be limiting factors from legal issues (Monopoly) to human limitations (Operating efficiently). The advanced technology that exists within those worlds is also another thing to consider which plays a key part in allowing them to adapt and grow in power and size out with realistic boundaries seen in modern day organisations.

Comment: Real world example: Mitsubishi Heavy Industries, which manufactures (among others) fighter aircraft, rockets, construction equipment, and air conditioners.

Comment: This may be a better question for the English Language stack exchange. When I see "Industries" in a company name, I think "they manufacture something". More real world examples: Fuji Heavy Industries, PTR Industries.

Comment: I don't think this is really a Worldbuilding question,. I second Aurast in that this is better fir the English SE.

Comment: In reality naming has no *required* association to what a company or group does.  There is no requirement for a company that creates manufactured goods to have *Industries* in their title.  I find this concept is particularly irritating in partisan political support groups.  For example...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Americans_for_Prosperity

Comment: @DustinJackson I'll third that.  Now I'm actually pretty interested to see what they have to say about it...

Comment: Also, I thought WY was the "Weyland-Yutani *Corporation*"?  Or am I confusing *Prometheus* with the *Alien* franchise (=P)?

Comment: After re-organising my thoughts, I have edited my question but the response from @Aurast and James are both very helpful in answering my question.

Comment: Even it it look like a decent question, I think it would be better elsewhere. Maybe at English language SE, like others mentioned, to discuss the real meaning of the word industry ?

Comment: Well I am familiar with what industry means and my assumption is that any organisation that includes the word "Industries" in its name will deal with two or more industries as part of its business model and not all industries results in the direct manufacturing of goods e.g. Financials or Utilities: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_Classification_Benchmark 

Maybe a better approach would be to try work with each organisation individually trying to match it with a close to real world example as possible instead of trying to infer some special grouping on the word Industry.